# Prevent IDM from downloading automatically in web api

Tags: c#, angularjs, pdf, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api method that returns an `HttpResponseMessage` containing a PDF file. The method looks something like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
return response;
```

When I call this api from client (which is written in angularJS), the Internet Download Manager automatically catches the PDF file and wants to download it. And because I have a security plan for my project, the IDM automatically requests username and password.
Does anyone have an idea about how I'm supposed to programmatically stop IDM from catching the PDF file?

**Update:** Here's my angularJS code:

```
$http.post(url, { transactionId: txId }
            , {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
            .success(function (response) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var printElem = angular.element('#printPdfLink');
                    printElem.attr('target', '_blank');
                    printElem.attr('href', reader.result);
                    printElem.attr('ng-click', '');
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            })
            .error(function (error) {});
```

Comment: If the answer of @Nkosi does not work for your issue, I think you should put your web api address into `"Don't start downloading automatically from the following sites:"` or `...addresses` in IDM Configuration (Options - File Types)

Comment: can you post your angular code which makes the api call?

Comment: @Kalyan updated the question

Comment: can you put a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on plunker or somewhere...I am interested to know if the code actually triggers a download or not?

Answer (score 10):

Change the mime type to `application/octet-stream` as a way to work around your problem. Make sure that the file name includes a proper file extension so that it can be recognized by the client system once downloaded.

Another issue is the `attachment` disposition of the content which typically forces it to save it as a file download. Change it to `inline` so that the client can consume it without IDM trying to download it as an attachment.

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamContent content new StreamContent(stream);
content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = content;
return response;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have try to use `HttpResponseMessage`.

If I use `ContentDisposition` is `inline` then response break the file. If use `attachment` then IDM can detect it.

At the end of the day, I found `Accept-Ranges` header can make download without IDM but it not valid in `HttpResponseMessage`.

You can try out my code below to make download file without IDM:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/download/{filename}")]
public void Download(string filename)
{
    // TODO lookup file path by {filename}
    // If you want to have "." in {filename} you need enable in webconfig
    string filePath = "<path>"; // your file path here
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("ContentDisposition", "attachment, filename=" + filename);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Note: `filename` parameter serve for download file name so you can config in `webconfig` if you want to have file extension (disabled by default).